# Any idea of printing in Racket?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I've been trying hard to do this and it's just frustrating that I can't actually do it. I'm even embarrassed of posting the code I wrote. I'm new to recursion so I need some help over here.
What I'm trying to do is to define a function star like this:

```
> (star 5)
*
**
***
****
*****
```

It should print  * and then ** in the next line and so on up to the number you put.
A classic beginner exercise but much more difficult in Racket with recursion. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't post your attempted solution, so I can only give you some hints, hoping that you reach the answer by your own; just fill-in the blanks ;).

It'll be easier if we split the problem in two parts. First, figure out how to create a string that's a repetition of another string `n` times - let's write a helper procedure for this:

```
(define (repeat s n)
  (cond ((zero? n) <???>) ; base case
        (else
         (string-append s
                        (repeat s <???>))))) ; advance recursion
```

Notice that we can also use `make-string` for a simpler answer, as demonstrated in @ThrowawayAccount3Million's answer. Anyway, the result should look like this:

```
(repeat "*" 3)
=> "***"
```

Now we just have to call it in the right place from our `star` procedure:

```
(define (star n)
  (cond ((not (zero? n))
         (star <???>) ; advance recursion
         (displayln (repeat <???> <???>))))) ; call helper
```

And that's it!

```
(star 5)
=> *
   **
   ***
   ****
   *****
```

Answer (score 2):

To iterate from 1 to 5 using nothing but recursion:

```
(let loop ((n 1))
    (cond ((> n 5)
           (void))
          (else
            (displayln ...)
            (loop (+ 1 n)))))
```

The above is equivalent to defining a function called `loop` and then calling it, like this:

```
(define (loop n)
    (cond ((> n 5)
           (void))
          (else
            (displayln ...)
            (loop (+ 1 n)))))
(loop 1)
```

This can appear inside the body of another function:

```
(define (stars num-stars)
    (define (loop ...
```

To print *n* stars:

```
 (displayln (make-string n #\*))
```

Racket isn't raw Scheme, and it has a looping construct of its own, which you could also use:

```
 (for ((n (in-range 1 6)))
    (displayln ...))
```

There's also a library that implements the `loop` construct from Common Lisp/Maclisp (which also has implementations for [Chicken Scheme](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/loop) and EMACS Lisp):

```
(require (planet jphelps/loop)) ;; Download, install, and
                                ;; use the library.
(loop for n from 1 to 5
    do (displayln ...))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to write a loop with a recursive function call:

```
(define (loop from to f done)
  (if (< from to)
      (begin
        (f from)
        (loop (+ from 1) to f done))
      (done)))
```

If `from` is smaller than `to` then loop calls a function `f` with the argument `from`, and then calls `loop` with `from+1`. If `from` is equal to `to` the loop is done and the function `done` is called.

```
Example:
> (loop 0 5 display newline)
01234
```

Let's define a helper that displays a single star:

```
(define (display-star _)
  (display "*"))
```

We can now define `display-stars` that displays `n` stars and finishes by printing a newline.

```
(define (display-stars n)
  (loop 0 n display-star newline))
```

The original problem can now be solved like this:

```
> (loop 1 6 display-stars void)
*
**
***
****
*****
```

The complete program:

```
#lang racket


(define (loop from to f done)
  (if (< from to)
      (begin
        (f from)
        (loop (+ from 1) to f done))
      (done)))


(define (display-stars n)
  (loop 0 n display-star newline))

(loop 1 6 display-stars void)
```

An alternative solution using the loop construct `for`:

```
> (for ([i (in-range 1 6)])
    (for ([j i])
      (display "*"))
    (newline))
*
**
***
****
*****
```